# Sheafification without using stalks?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Most definitions of sheafification either use stalks or (co)limits. Can we avoid that, at least in some nice cases? Say $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on a topological space $X$, thought of as functions with certain properties. For $U\subseteq X$ open, call $(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}$ a generalized function if $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $U$, $f_i\in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$ and they are compatible, i.e., $f_i$ and $f_j$ agree on $U_i\cap U_j$. Identify two generalized functions $(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(g_j,V_j)_{j\in J}$ if they cover the same open set $U$, and there is another open cover $(W_k)_k$ of $U$ such that $f_i$ agree with $g_j$ on $U_i\cap V_k\cap W_k$ for all $i,j,k$; I think this is equivalent to the existence of $(W_k)_k$ a common refinement of $(U_i)_i$ and $(V_j)_j$, and $f_i,g_j$ agreeing on $W_k$.

Can we define the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^\sharp$ by letting $\mathcal{F}^\sharp(U)$ be all the equivalence classes of generalized functions on $U$? Or if this disagree with the standard definition is there a simple counterexample? Is it even a sheaf?

Edit: It seems it is standard that this works for **separated** presheaf, namely if two function agree on an open cover then they agree, but it doesn't work in general (although it does make the presheaf separate, and thus applying twice would work). Here is the argument. Use $[(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}]$ to denoted the equivalence class of $(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}$. If $W\subseteq U$ is open, the restriction of $[(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}]$ to $W$ is $[(f_i|_{U_i\cap W},U_i\cap W)_{i\in I}]$. For simplicity say we have two classes [$(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}]$ and $[(g_j,V_j)_{j\in J}]$ that are compatible, that is the restrictions of $(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(g_j,V_j)_{j\in J}$ to $U\cap V$ are equivalent. I claim that $(f_i,U_i)_{i\in I}\cup(g_j,V_j)_{j\in J}$ is a generalized function, which means $f_i$ and $g_j$ agree on $U_i\cap V_j$. What we know is that $f_i$ and $g_j$ agree on $U_i\cap V_j\cap W_k$ for some open cover $(W_k)_k$ of $U\cap V$. To deduce that $f_i$ and $g_j$ agree on $U_i\cap V_j$ we do want the presheaf we started with to be separated.

Comment: There is a very general approach to sheafification which involves the notion of a Lawvere-Tierney topology. It requires some knowledge of topos theory, however.

Comment: The so-called Grothendieck plus construction is basically what you describe. It does not sheafify in general, but doing it twice does.

Comment: I just wanted to mention there is a way to "sheafify without sheafify", using the theory of frame-valued sets. In this context, for a frame $A$ you have several categories of presheaf-like objects associated to $A$. One of them (the category of displays) is equivalent to the presheaf category and another one (the category of $A$-sets) is equivalent to the category of sheaves on $A$. Meanwhile, the sheafification functor does nothing to the objects and instead just changes the morphisms between them. For more on this, see Borceux, Handbook of categorical algebra III.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your construction is the Grothendieck $+$ construction. In fact, although it may not be obvious to you, your approach uses limits and colimits.

Recall that a *sieve* is a set $K$ of open sets such that for all open $V \subseteq W \in K$, $V \in K$. If $\bigcup\limits_{V \in K} V = U$, $K$ is said to be a cover of $U$. In other words, a cover of $U$ is an open cover which is also a sieve. Denote the set of covers of $U$ by $sieve(U)$. Note that $sieve : Sets^{\mathcal{O}_X^{op}}$ is actually a presheaf of sets. $\DeclareMathOperator{colim}{colim}$

Every open cover $\{U_i \mid i \in I\}$ of $U$ gives rise to the sieve $toSieve((U_i)_{i \in I}) := \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \{V$ open $\mid V \subseteq U_i\}$.

It turns out that your set of “generalised functions” on $U$ is just $\colim_{K \in sieve(U)} \lim_{V \in K} \mathcal{F}(V)$. Indeed, given a generalised function $(f_i, U_i)_{i \in I}$, let $K = toSieve((U_i)_{i \in I})$. Then we can extend $f$ uniquely to an element $g \in \lim_{V \in K} \mathcal{F}(V)$ by defining, for $V \subseteq U_i$, $g_V = f_{U_i}|_V$.

Your condition for when one should consider two “generalised functions” to be equal corresponds precisely to taking the colimit over all sieves. Define the resulting preshead to be $\mathcal{F}^+$.

The good news is that you are on the right track, and this $+$ construction can be used to construct the sheafification. The bad news is that you actually have to apply it twice - the construction is thus known as the $++$ construction.

To show you can’t get away with just one application (except for $X$ trivial), take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the constant presheaf on $S$, where $S$ is any set with at least two distinct elements. That is, $\mathcal{F}(U) = S$ for all $U$, with restrictions being the identity map. Then $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ will be $S$ for nonempty $U$ and $1$ for $U = \emptyset$. This is not a sheaf unless every open subset of $X$ is connected.

You were correct to note that $+$ results in a sheaf when applied to a separated presheaf. It is a no-op when applied to a sheaf. And it gives a separated presheaf when applied to any presheaf.

For more details on why $++$ gives the sheafification, you should consult a text. I first learned it from *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*. It takes about 5 pages, so I won’t recount the proof here.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{F}^+(S)(U)$? Is it $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$? My understanding is that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ consists of constant functions on $U$ and $\mathcal{F}^{++}(U)$ should consist of locally constant functions on $U$, namely a partition of $U$ into disjoint open sets and asign an $S$-value to each. Isn't that just a "generalized function", so $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ already does it?

Comment: @xXF I have corrected the typo you mentioned and provided an explicit definition of $\mathcal{F}$. $\mathcal{F}$ is not the presheaf of constant functions to $S$ because then we would have $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset) = 1$. However, $\mathcal{F}^+$ is the presheaf of constant functions to $S$. And of course $\mathcal{F}^{++}$ is the sheaf of locally constant functions to $S$.

Comment: I saw a detailed explanation elsewhere. So the point is that empty set is an open cover of itself! I thought nobody other than logicians care about empty set...

Comment: @xXF The empty set is important and fundamental. There are all kinds of cases where the empty set is useful. Ultimately, all mathematicians should learn to love it IMO.